# What changes in the skeletal system should be needed to support a head that is 8 times larger?

Tags: biology

When I was in the process of designing a human with a head that has 8 times the amount of brain matter than a normal one. I came into a problem.

What kind of neck muscles are capable of lifting a 75 pound head? And even if that were possible, would there still be issues when it comes to balance and walking on two legs? If So, Any solutions with no involvement of any mechanical support?

Answer (score 3):

Our present neck has already its nice troubles: the neck muscles are 4 times closer to the pivot point than the applied load, meaning that they need to exert a force 4 times bigger than the applied load to balance the head movements.

Now you are multiplying that load by a factor 8. Your humans are going to have some serious neck pain if their neck muscles have to handle 300 pound!

The only way I see to effectively support that load is a shortening of the neck and a massive reduction of the neck mobility.

Comment: Doesn't sound too bad for what I'm creating, but how would the body be able to even balance itself when standing upright?

Comment: @Red_Wasp like [that](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrying_on_the_head)?

Answer (score 1):

> And even if that were possible, would there still be issues when it comes to **balance** and walking on two legs?

Absolutely!

Imagine this woman (pic taken from a comment by @Molot) bending over -- or, in fact, doing *anything* other than moving upright and slowly.

And then there's childbirth.  It's problematic enough already with the existing large human head.  Then, how does the baby even lift its head, much less crawl or even stand up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issues with muscle strength. There are plenty of examples like this here: https://www.oldtimestrongman.com/blog/tag/wrestlers-bridge/

There are pretty insane wrestlers bridge.

Shorten the neck, and make it thick (along with some thick trapezius for some added support) and you'll be fine.

For added mobility and balance, you should make them small and stocky. A big head elevates the center of gravity which should be balanced out. Give them wider hips to widen the base and a big trunk to secure them if they want to cut corners a bit sharper.

Answer (score 0):

If we can live with some restrictions, this is totally possible.

Let's look at the human body. Lumbar section of vertebral column already supports 75 pounds and even more than that. If we sacrifice our slender necks and would have a neck that gradually transitions into a head, this kind of neck would have no problem supporting a 75 lbs head. Of course this neck will be less mobile than our current one, but still capable of quick movement.

Body balance would also become more precarious, unless we want to put more "ballast" into lower body parts.

Answer (score -2):

There is a question here about muliple or distributed brains. Here is  reason for that to happen.  Put small brains directly behind manipulators and sense organs, but the main “thinking” brain in the center of the body.  That is, rather than having each more advanced brain system wrapped around or adjecent to the old, have it grow in a separate organ.

Comment: This could be a nice solution, but the whole purpose for the extra brain matter is to allow the creature to perform multiple tasks without really thinking about it. [Kind of like a habit of breathing or walking but at a much more complex degree]. At the same time all of the extra brain matter not in automation can be used for thinking many complex things  in a level no normal human can cope with. So would relocating the extra brain make a difference to what I just said?